# Is the set of finite undirected graphs countably infinite?

Tags: graph-theory

Consider the set of all undirected graphs with a finite number of nodes and a finite number of edges, is this set countably infinite?

The infinite part is obvious but the mapping to a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ does not seem obvious at all.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Show that for each $n$ the set $A_n$ of graphs with $n$ vertices is finite.

Your set is $\cup_n A_n$ which is a countable union of finite sets.

Comment: Where is the surjective part of the mapping to $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @JérômeVerstrynge It is well known that countable union of finite sets is countable. If you are not familiar with this, let $|A_k|=n_k$. Construct a bijection by sending each $A_k$ to the set $\{ n_1+...+n_{k-1}+1, n_1+...+n_{k-1}+2,..., n_1+...+n_{k-1}+n_k \}$.